# iab.taxonome.org error code -5

Tags: classification, categories, taxonomy, text-classification, custom-taxonomy

i'm trying to use iab.taxonome.org service to classify texts, and get error response -5 (text too short)

Here is what i'm sending to the service:
https://rest.taxonome.org/v1/taxono?me=A college basketball game at Allen Fieldhouse, in Lawrence, Kansas, the home of the Kansas Jayhawks
The history of basketball is traced back to a YMCA International Training School, known today as Springfield College, located in Springfield, Massachusetts&token=[...MyKey...]&ver=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed I had the same issue. After clearing this with taxonome support team I figure out there is a requirement for at least 500 words per classification.
I have asked to add it to the API reference page.

Double checking and editing my answer: It is depends which framework is being used to send this data. In case you are implementing the client and not encoding the URL string it won't work for you (e.g. space = %20).
Check the API example here:
https://iab.taxonome.org/api

Comment: I tried to send a longer text, still can't get the taxonomy classification.